# How to specify working directory for ENTRYPOINT in Dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile

The Docker image (Windows-based) includes an application directory at `C:\App`. Inside that directory reside several sub-folders and files, including a batch file called `process.bat`. The Dockerfile (used to build the image) ends like this:

```
ENTRYPOINT [ "C:\\App\\process.bat" ]
```

When I instantiate this image using the command: `docker run company/app`, the batch file runs, but it fails at the point where other files under `C:\App` are referenced. Essentially, the working directory is still `C:\` from the Docker container's entry-point.

Is there a way to set the working directory within the Dockerfile? Couple of alternatives do exist:

- Add `-w C:\App` to the docker run
- In the batch file, I can add a line at the beginning `cd /D C:\App`

But is there a way to specify the working directory in the Dockerfile?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

`WORKDIR /App` is a command you can use in your dockerfile to change the working directory.

Comment: Yup, `WORKDIR` changes the CWD for the command specified in `ENTRYPOINT`.

Answer (score 29):

If `/App` is a mounted volume then you should specify `VOLUME /App` before `WORKDIR` to use it with `ENTRYPOINT`, otherwise it does not be seen by `ENTRYPOINT`:

```
VOLUME ["/App"]
WORKDIR /App
ENTRYPOINT ["sh", "start.sh"]
```

Which `start.sh` is within `/App` directory.

Comment: This doesn't work if you are using the image build by that Dockerfile to build another image, whose Dockerfile which might not set the same `WORKDIR` back to the original location at the end.

Comment: @JoshM. This is for runtime man. This is not for manipulating and using files in the process of building an image. This get used when the image is **ran** as a container.