# Docker Java OpenJdk Container can't access Files

Tags: java, docker

Given this docker file

```
FROM openjdk:latest
COPY WebGenerator-1.0.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar /usr/local/lib/WebGenerator.jar
COPY webgenerator /usr/local/lib/webgenerator
EXPOSE 8085
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/usr/local/lib/WebGenerator.jar"]
```

I build an image that runs WebGenerator. The jar works smoothly, it can access resources embedded inside the jar and export is services, but it cannot access the files inside the folder `webgenerator`.

Please note that:

- The file are normally accessible when the jar is launched in the same context outside the container
- The folder and all its structure is correctly copied inside the container. I double checked that copying the whole `/usr/local/lib` folder within the container inside the host and checking if everything was there. Permissions are also OK, a+rx. And yes, in case you're wondering, webgenerator is a subfolder in lib.

I need a hint to understand why java can't access those files.

For sake of completeness here are the commands I use to build and run the container.

```
docker build -f WebGenerator.docker -t webgenerator:1.1 .
docker run -it webgenerator:1.1
```

Comment: What exception are you getting? Do you need to set the current working directory to make any relative file paths work?

Comment: I just can't access to the files, for Example
`new File("webgenerator/wg_site/index.html").exists()` return false.
(And just within the container, even if the files are clearly there).
The current working directory should be the same... but... maybe you're right, maybe that is different in the container! I'm going to try.

Comment: With that relative path, you have to set the working directory to `/usr/local/lib`.

Comment: @Thilo, YES, that was it... I add to add WORKDIR, because the container launcher reside in another directory... Thank you, I can't upvote, but I can accept the answer in case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `new File("webgenerator/wg_site/index.html").exists()` return false.

With that relative path, you have to [set the working directory](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45721213/14955) in your container to `/usr/local/lib`.

```
WORKDIR /usr/local/lib
```

Depending what this tool does, you may want to not copy the files from your host into the image, but rather mount them as a volume into the container (so that the process can create and update files on the host for you). That would be the normal setup if this is something like a compiler that creates files that you then want to use on the host. That way, you don't have to rebuild the image every time you change a source file.